# Newtonsoft JSON SnakeCase with combination of the number in name of the property in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

Im using .net core webapi project with swagger, and when I put this request into my swagger:

```
{
  "year": 2023,
  "vat_amount": 2000,
  "vat_period": "January",
  "vat_amount_20": 2000,
  "turnover_description": "Some description of turnover",
  "turnover_description_10": "Turnover Description 10",
  "turnover_description_20": "Turnover Description 20",
  "related_party_identifier": "106723546"
}
```

Newtonsoft.JSON recognize everything except where props are with alphanumeric combination: `vat_amount_20`, `turnover_description_10`, `turnover_description_20` these fields are not populated in my dto model:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(SnakeCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class VatRecordingIndividualRequestDto
{
    [JsonProperty("turnover_description")]
    public string? TurnoverDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("turnover_description_10")]
    public string? TurnoverDescription10 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("turnover_description_20")]
    public string? TurnoverDescription20 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vat_amount_20")]
    public double? VatAmount20 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vat_amount")]
    public double? VatAmount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vat_period")]
    public string? VatPeriod { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

In my program.cs I setup my JsonOptions for SnakeCasePropertyNamingPolicy:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCasePropertyNamingPolicy();
});
```

Also Im calling this class from this code:

```
public class SnakeCasePropertyNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        return name.ToSnakeCase();
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToSnakeCase(this string str)
    {
        return string.Concat(str.Select((character, index) =>
                index > 0 && char.IsUpper(character)
                    ? "_" + character
                    : character.ToString()))
            .ToLower();
    }
}
```

**How can I force my dto model to take into consideration following poperties from json for example:** **foo_bar_1**?

Comment: You have both a naming Policy and you explicitly set property names. I haven't seen interference between the two before, but your policy should also not be in effect where you have explicit name mapping.

Comment: Just leave only  jsonproperty attribute and remove all another code that mentions naming policy.

Comment: I think you are mixing up attributes and classes from Json.NET and System.Text.Json.  [`JsonNamingPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonnamingpolicy) and [`AddJsonOptions()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvcbuilderextensions.addjsonoptions) are for **System.Text.Json** so that's the serializer you are actually using, but [`[JsonProperty]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) is from **Newtonsoft.Json** which System.Text.Json ignores.

Comment: Try adding the attribute [`[System.Text.Json.Serialization("vat_amount_20")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) and see if the problem resolves.

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle the numbers right? This should insert an underscore when it finds a number preceded by a non-number character.

```
public static string ToSnakeCase(this string str)
{
    return string.Concat(str.Select((character, index) =>
            index > 0 && (char.IsUpper(character) || (char.IsNumber(character) && !char.IsNumber(str, index - 1)))
                ? "_" + character
                : character.ToString()))
        .ToLower();
}
```